# Adding Classes Based on Positive/Negative and Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find a way to add a class to a td based on whether it's positive or  negative, not within the first `<tr>` and not within the first `<td>` of a `<tr>`.

I can't find much on the either issue through searching. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Sorry - what do you mean by positive/negative?

Comment: Do you mean contains a number that is positive/negative? Or if the row is odd/even in the table?

Comment: haha! @Rev, had you framed your question a bit specific, you might have got an answer by now. :P

Comment: yea, sorry, I mean like 100 version -100, it's a numeric value. I was in a bit of a rush lol.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. What is it that has numeric value +/-100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean if the `<td>` contains a positive or negative number? If that's what you're trying to do, you could use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr:not(:first)").find("td:not(:first)").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() > 0)
            $(this).addClass("positive");
        else if ($(this).text() < 0)
            $(this).addClass("negative");
    })
});
```

I tested this on the following table and it worked fine:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>-4</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-7</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>144</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just a thought on a possible edge-case: what should happen if the number is `0`?

Comment: @David Thomas - If the number is 0, it's technically neither negative or positive, and OP said he was adding a class based on whether it was positive or negative. I coded it so no class was added, but the asker can change that functionality if he wants.

Comment: Understood; that's why I said 'possible' =) the question was more to the OP, as a request for clarity.

Comment: Oops. I misread "should" as "would." Reading that correctly, it's pretty obvious your question is to the OP, lol.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`nth-child selector`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
 $('td:not(:first):nth-child(2n)').addClass('class')
```